# Docker running a command on container start up

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile

I have a docker container, for which I need to run the following command

```
php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work &
```

It starts a worker process that looks for jobs and executes them.

I can run it by doing exec -it when the container is running.

But I need to do it using Dockerfile so that when my container re-deploys, it starts this automatically. I have tried

```
RUN php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work

CMD ["php","/var/www/html/artisan","queue:work"]

ENTRYPOINT ["php","/var/www/html/artisan","queue:work"]
```

separately of course. but none of them work. In the case of CMD and ENTRYPOINT my container starts giving out a 502 error and my service becomes inaccessible.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looking at the logs with `docker logs <container_name>` will certainly help us to understand why the container isn't starting.

Comment: Try running the command this way:
```CMD ["/bin/bash","-c","php","/var/www/html/artisan","queue:work && tail -f /dev/null"]```

Comment: Are you trying to launch the worker in the same container as something else?  Usually you'd launch only one process per container; use a second container (based on the same image but with a different command) to launch the worker.

Comment: Yes i want to do both in the same container..

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in multiple ways.

You could write a shell script that starts the background process first and then starts your API.

```
CMD ["./start_server.sh"]
```

Contents of `./start_server.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work &

exec php-server-serving-api
```

You could also do this through a docker entrypoint shell script

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-server-serving-api"]
```

Contents of `./docker-entrypoint.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

php /var/www/html/artisan queue:work &

exec $@
```

However, what I recommend is, if they are separate type of workloads, run them in separate container. If the background processing task crashes, there is no one to restart it. If you run it as a separate container, you could use a system to restart it.

Comment: regarding running them in separate conatiners..can that be done using the same docker file?

Comment: Yes possible with the same docker file. Build image. When you start the container pass different arguments to start. E.g `docker run image ./start-server.sh` and `docker run image./start-worker.sh` provided both scripts are copied in the dockerfile into the image so that it knows how to start the api and the worker